# Add link to backstretch slides

Tags: jquery, jquery-backstretch

I'm currently altering an existing website which is using Backstretch for a fullscreen slideshow as the site is using a parallax effect as well. The alteration I need to make is to add a different link to each slide. I've used backstretch a lot but never had to do something like this with it.

So for example, slide 1 needs to link to google.com; slide 2 to yahoo.com and so on.

Is this at all possible with this plugin?

Comment: I guess it is not possible if you don't your own plugin similar to backstretch.

Comment: It is not so hard to implement similar. You will change opacity thats all